# How to work with files in aspnetcore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0

how to work with files in dotnetcore.

For example we had this before:

```
IFormFile file // you would get this by uploading a file
file.SaveAs(filePath);
```

How can i check if file exist. How can i dynamicaly add new files ...
Couldnt find anything about working with files in aspnetcore.

Comment: Can you give more precisions about add new files dynamicaly ? What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Everything is clear now :) its same as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as before to check if file exists :

```
File.Exists(filepath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the file using Exists() method of File class.

```
bool exists = File.Exists(filePath);
if(!exists )
{
     file.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/FileProviders/index.html

There is a list of classes and interfaces you may use to get what you want...